# How to achieve the EPPlus Iteration functionality using ClosedXML library in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus, closedxml

I have the following code which iterates over a range in excel worksheet using EPPlus library, now I want to achieve the same functionality using ClosedXML Library:

```
 ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
 {
     table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
 }
```

What I've tried:

```
 ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Range(1,1,LastRowUsed().RowNumber(),LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber()))
 {
     table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Value.ToString());
 }
```

But it throws an exception that foreach cannot iterate over IXLRange type variable as it doesn't have any GetEnumerator definition, so how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Cells()` property to iterate over the cells in the range (and compared to your original code, you should replace `LastRowUsed().RowNumber()` also, or was this deliberate?):

```
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Range(1,1,1,LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber()).Cells())
{
    table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Value.ToString());
}
```